# "Invalid universal id" error while getting parent UNID for Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have wrote the follwing code o get the parent UNID of a response document. But I am getting "Invalid universal ID" error. But when I create a doclink using the "$Ref" I am able to access the parent doc using doclink. I want to access the parent document and change the one of the field in parent document. Can anyone suggest anything?

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim uiwork As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

Dim doc As NotesDocument  
Dim parent As Notesdocument     

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase 
Set uidoc=uiwork.currentdocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document

'Set parent = db.GetDocumentByUNID(doc.ParentDocumentUNID)
Set parent = db.GetDocumentByUNID("doc.$Ref")
'both methods are giving same error
```

Answer (score 3):

what does doc.isresponse return?

using parent unid should be fine. However

==>Set parent = db.GetDocumentByUNID("doc.$Ref")

is invalid, should have been:

```
if doc.hasItem("$Ref") then
   Set parent = db.GetDocumentByUNID(doc.~$Ref(0))
end if
```

or

```
if doc.hasItem("$Ref") then
   Set parent = db.GetDocumentByUNID(doc.getItemValue("$Ref")(0))
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim. I wrote the code in QuerySave and it worked fine. It was giving invalid UNID because I was trying to get it before the document is saved.